# Why does I2C On Nano Fail with LiquidCrystal_I2C library unless Nano runs at 8Mhz?

Tags: arduino-nano, lcd, atmega328

I have an Arduino Nano (running by default at 16Mhz).
I am connecting a 20x4 LCD screen via I2C (using A4 for SDA and A5 for SCL).

Here's the very simple code (which was previously only showing black blocks on the screen -- but now seems to be showing odd chars).
[image: LCD bad chars]

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F, 20, 4);

void setup() {
 lcd.begin();

  lcd.setCursor(2,0);
  lcd.print("test this");
}

void loop() {
  lcd.setCursor(5,2);
  lcd.print("Hello, world!");
}
```

**ATmega328P DIP Circuit**

I've been using this same LCD screen in another circuit which uses a raw ATMega382P (DIP) and it works 100% fine.

I put the LCD back into the circuit with the DIP, tested it and it works fine.

Then I remembered, that ATMega328P DIP runs at 8Mhz.

**Run At 8Mhz**

So that gave me the idea of running my Nano at 8Mhz just to see if it would work.

I altered the previous program just to set the CPU speed.  Here's the entire code again and a snapshot of it working.

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <avr/power.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F, 20, 4);

void setup() {
   clock_prescale_set(clock_div_2);  // Sets to 8Mhz
 lcd.begin();

  lcd.setCursor(2,0);
  lcd.print("test this");
}

void loop() {
  lcd.setCursor(5,2);
  lcd.print("Hello, world!");
}
```

[image: LCD 16Mhz]

**Questions**

I've never changed anything on that LCD. 
Is there something I'm missing?
I thought the SCL line (which is driven by the CPU) set the speed anyways??? -- -- and the LCD was just a slave.

Do you know of any reasons why this would behave this way?
Is there something I can change to run it at 16Mhz?

Comment: Can you print the value of the macro `F_CPU` on the serial monitor (or LCD)? Maybe the code (`Wire.h`) has compile-time checks for the clock speed and adjusts `TWBRn` wrong? (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf chapter 26.5.2)

Comment: As soon as I read your comment it flipped a switch on in my brain and I remembered what I have done. I feel a bit foolish.  I altered my boards.txt so it has this line : nano.build.f_cpu=8000000L  which is setting it to build for 8Mhz.  I was doing that because I use Arduino IDE to build HEX files for my ATmega328P DIP and then I use AVR Dude to flash them to my chip.  I'm running ATmega328P DIPs on internal 8Mhz.  Thanks very much, I wouldn't have remembered that I had altered that.

Comment: Wow, that was a quite a shot into the dark but I hit something :D. Doesn't the Arduino IDE have specific board variants for 8MHz and 16MHz variants which you could use? Anyways, I guess you can write your own answer to the question and accept it.